# Open image in new window

Tags: javascript, image

How can I open an image in a new window by using its `id`?

```
function swipe()
{   
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.style.width=200+"px";
    largeImage.style.height=200+"px";                   
}
```

This function is called on click on the image. Right now, it's opening in the same window, but I want to open it in a new window. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
function swipe() {
   var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
   largeImage.style.display = 'block';
   largeImage.style.width=200+"px";
   largeImage.style.height=200+"px";
   var url=largeImage.getAttribute('src');
   window.open(url,'Image','width=largeImage.stylewidth,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1');
}
```

HTML code:

```
<img src="abc.jpg" onClick="swipe();"/>
```

Answer (score 16):

For a new window that has a good chance of being lost behind the main window, and generally annoying visitors:

```
window.open('http://example.com/someImage.png');
```

I'd just stick to a regular link if I were you.

Comment: Currently on Chrome, I have to refresh to see the image. Using absolute URL too

Comment: Why would you assume he's working on customer-facing code and not debugging tools or building an extremely useful feature for specific use? He asked an abstract question. He deserves an abstract answer.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
<img src="URL or BASE64" onclick="window.open(this.src)" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Comment: I get this error from Chrome: ```Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL```

Answer (score 6):

Try with the following function:

```
function newTabImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = $('#idimage').attr('src');

    var w = window.open("",'_blank');
    w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
    w.document.close(); 
}
```

Call with this HTML code:

```
<img id="idimage" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4A.." onclick="newTabImage()">
```

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="test">
```

JavaScript

```
    function test(){
    url = "https://www.google.de//images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    img = '<img src="'+url+'">';
    popup = window.open();
    popup.document.write(img);                        
    popup.print();
    }
```

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ne6f5axj/10/

You have to put the url of image in an image-tag.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
window.open(url,'htmlname','width=largeImage.stylewidth,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1');}
```

But you might run in trouble, if someone uses AdBlock or any PopUp-Blocker.

Answer (score -6):

```
window.Open("http://yourdomain.com/yourimage.gif");
```

Comment: You may want to edit your answer. `window.Open` isn't a method and will cause an error if you try to use it instead of `window.open`.