# show image in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, image, window

I am currently trying to open an image in a new window by clicking on it. But i cant seem to figure out where my code is wrong. Any solution?

```
function largePic(){

var imageNumber = document.getElementById("img2");
imageNumber = this.getAttribute('src').split(".", 1);
window.open(imageNumber[0] + "zlatan-stor.jpg");

}
```

Comment: you are currently doing this.getAttribute, try imageNumber.getAttribute('src').split(".", 1);

Comment: did yo try to log URL you're trying to open(`console.log`)? What happens if you just put created URL into browser address line? Can you open any other non-related URL with `window.open`?

Comment: the previous image, that i click on is not being replaced with the new one. file:///C:/Users/Walid/Desktop/Skola/Webbteknologi-Databaser/Delkurs2/Inl%C3%A4mning6/zlatanzlatan-stor.jpg , as you can see zlatan stays, and then come zlatan-stor.jpg. and i have no file called zlatanzlatan-stor.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try changing "`this.getAttribute('src').split(".",1);`" to

```
imageNumber.getAttribute('src').split(".",1);
```

Comment: it did open a new window, but the image is not shown. i get an error instead that it couldnt find the image.

Comment: What is the URL of the window opening? Prehaps you should try "http://"+imageNumber[0]+'zlatan-stor.jpg" as the window url

Comment: the situation is that it somehow doesnt replace the previous image, that i am clicking on. file:///C:/Users/Walid/Desktop/Skola/Webbteknologi-Databaser/Delkurs2/Inl%C3%A4mning6/zlatanzlatan-stor.jpg , as you can see, it has the name of the previous image there, zlatan, and then come the new one zlatam-stor.jpg

Comment: Oh i see. Well, that is because you ask it to use the name small image + the big image. try window.open(imageNumber[0] + "-stor.jpg"); and i bet you will see the magic :-)

Comment: Du är välkommen, bra kväll!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that #img2 is the one being clicked? If it isn't just do it like this:

```
function largePic(){

   var imageNumber = document.getElementById("img2");
   var link = imageNumber.getAttribute('src').split(".", 1);
   window.open(link[0] + "zlatan-stor.jpg");

}
```

**this** will work only if the function is called inline (which you shouldn't do it, you should have your js code in a separated file)

Comment: Man that was my answer. haha :-) Nice to see you once again Skatox.

Comment: Yes, the id is img2. <img id="img2" src="zlatan.jpg" onclick="largePic();" alt="Zlatan">. but it doesnt find the image, just opens a new window.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window) is very similar to yours.

I think the main problem with your code is that  `window.open` expects a URL and one isn't being provided.

Following the answer found at this link should allow you to separate the code into an external file, which as @Skatox mentioned, is a good practice.

Comment: i have this js code in a separate file. and then i call the function where the img is, like this. <img id="img2" src="zlatan.jpg" onclick="largePic();" alt="Zlatan">