# javascript:window.open to open an image , it works but also changes the first page

Tags: javascript, window.open

When I click on the link, it works and open a new window and shows the image but the main page also changes to a new page with this url address :

```
javascript:window.open('documents/receive_proof_1_2015-08-07_94583855.jpg', 'yourWindowName', 'width=400,height=330');
```

my code :

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(\'documents/'.$row['proof'].'\', \'yourWindowName\', \'width=400,height=330\');">Test</a>'
```

Comment: Try the 'onclick' attribute instead of the `href`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open image in new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window)

Comment: Try adding `return false;` after the semi-colon

Comment: this works :
<a href="documents/'.$row['proof'].'" onclick="pop_up(this); return false;"> <img src="images/dthumb.png" style="height:30px;"></a>

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking on an `a` tag with a not-empty `href` attribute: of course the browser will redirect you to the `href` value. I suggest you to not use the `href` attribute for javascript; either use the `onclick` attribute or (better) use jQuery to attach the event to the tag.

Comment: Plain JS is fine too as this question isn't tagged with jQuery.