# open image in new window blank page appearing javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, window

after taking the reference from this answer

[Open image in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window)

i did the the same code.

```
function openImage() {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('viewImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.style.width = 200 + "px";
    largeImage.style.height = 200 + "px";
    var url = largeImage.getAttribute('src');
    window.open(url, 'Image', 'width=largeImage.stylewidth,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1');
}
```

but when this function executed, blank page is showing
when i view image src in console, it is showing proper data.[image]

my img element is also showing me image properly,
[image]

but this is how my page is being shown[image: enter code here]

what do you think what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you provide complete html code?

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML content and not the screenshots?

Comment: That solution is for image with actual url as src, for an image with base64 encoded data as src refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798126/how-to-open-the-newly-created-image-in-a-new-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solution is for image with actual url as src, in your case image src is a base64 encoded string not url.

Base64 support for Window.open is not same across all browsers, it works on firefox but it won't work on chrome and IE.

So, you can try this instead

```
function openImage() {
    var largeImage = document.getElementById('viewImage');
    largeImage.style.display = 'block';
    largeImage.style.width = 200 + "px";
    largeImage.style.height = 200 + "px";

    var w = window.open("");
    w.document.write(largeImage.outerHTML);
}
```

Comment: cannot read property document of null ` w.document.write(largeImage.outerHTML);`

Comment: As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open, window.open returns null if window couldn't be opened. Can you post the exact code you have tried?

Comment: I fixed that issue

Comment: I need to allow the popup in my chrome

Comment: Nice :) have fun