# How come some URL view the image in web browser and some just trigger a file download?

Tags: image, jpeg, html

Trigger a file download:
https://alwaysepst.blob.core.windows.net/ulm-my/Projects/UnileverMT/CompetitorReport/201901/AeonBigAmpangOverdue11days_20190111T170348680.jpg

Opens a webpage:
http://personal.psu.edu/xqz5228/jpg.jpg

Comment: Sometimes there's JS working behind the scenes on some servers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript/6799284#6799284

Comment: If you change the MIME TYPE, you can change whether the browser downloads or opens in an internal viewer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some images automatically download when their URL is visited and others not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345343/why-do-some-images-automatically-download-when-their-url-is-visited-and-others-n)

Answer (score 1):

The server that the first url points to returns a header `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` which tells the browser to trigger a file download whereas the second url has a header `Content-Type: image/jpeg` which the browser is able to interpret by itself as an image file.

If you were trying to create this behaviour, the first example isn't really an accepted way of triggering a download. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/9746995) for more details on that.

There's also a `download` attribute for the `a` element in html. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).