# Display an image by clicking on button

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to display an image on new window after clicking on button.

However, some time, that cannot be done.

**Component.ts**

```
displayMyImage()
    {
    this.http.get(this.imagePath, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(map(res =>
            {
               return new Blob([res.body], {type: res.headers.get('Content-Type')});
            })).subscribe(hi =>
            {
                const xx = URL.createObjectURL(hi);
                window.open(xx);
            });
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<span (click)='displayMyImage()'>Display</span>
```

or

```
<button (click)="displayMyImage()">Display</button>
```

I got [that exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY3UH.png)

Could you please tell me what I missed ?. Big thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open image in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908022/open-image-in-new-window)

Comment: Hello Sir @ChintanJoshi, thanks a lot for your replay. I tried the correct answer of your proposed thread and that didn't worked for me knowing that the value of **largeImage** is `../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg`. Have you please any idea about solving that?. Big Thanks.

Comment: What is imagePath in your case ?

Comment: If I used **staticPath** as `<img id="staticPath" src="../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg" style="max-width:100px">` --> It worked as well. But if I used **dynamicPath** like `<input id='dynamicPath' type="text" value="{{saria2020()}}">` --> That doesn't worked, **knowing that** the value of **saria2020** is `../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg` presented on **component.ts** like that `saria2020() : String{return this.specialUser.displayPathImage;}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that would help.

```
document.getElementById('bigpic').style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare function as below to get image-preview. I suppose that you have imagePath there.

```
displayMyImage() {

    var imagePath = "https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/shutterstock_1006988770.png";
    window.open(
      imagePath,
      "Image",
      "width=largeImage.stylewidth,height=largeImage.style.height,resizable=1"
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I used **staticPath** as `<img id="staticPath" src="../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg" style="max-width:100px">` --> It worked as well. But if I used **dynamicPath** like `<input id='dynamicPath' type="text" value="{{saria2020()}}">` --> That doesn't worked, **knowing that** the value of **saria2020** is `../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg` presented on **component.ts** like that `saria2020() : String{return this.specialUser.displayPathImage;}`

Comment: So my problem is with dynamic path. I can't know how solving that ?.

Comment: Are you getting dynamicPath as URL or static path ?

Comment: still not working Sir, using **static path**, I can display the image with url `localhost:4300/assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg`,  but using **dynamicPath** with {{saria2020}} instead {{saria2020()}} I got nothing with url `localhost:4300/null`

Comment: the **dynamicPath** id a dynamic path . It is the result of `saria2020() : String{return this.specialUser.displayPathImage;}` which is `../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg`

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand, whether you want to test static-path or dynamic path ?

Comment: My **only** problem is with **dynamicPath**

Comment: By dynamicPath, you meant to say Image_URL or image from your local ?

Comment: That exactly what I did Sir, I used in **component.ts**, the function `saria2020() : String{return this.specialUser.displayPathImage;}` which returns `../assets/upload/Ordinaryespdsi2019o4f8dh1584349128317.jpg` (exists on my local)

Comment: Should be path issue. See this example I have editted on stackblitz here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-assets-image-test-ep3dsy

Comment: Thanks Sir it works as well when I specify the pathImage, but when I made it as dynamic like `getLocalImage() {
    this.specialUser.displayPathImage;
  }`,  I can't show the image.

knowing that **specialUser** is defined like that:
`var requestb = new XMLHttpRequest();
        requestb.open('GET', 'http://localhost:6227/api/auth/users/' + this.usrId, false);
        requestb.send(null);

        this.specialUser = JSON.parse(requestb.responseText);`